# WebdriverIO throwing error "unknown command chrome"

Tags: node.js, testing, webdriver, webdriver-io, saucelabs

I am trying to run my automation tests on sauce labs using sauce connect. However, after configuring my config file I was unable to successfully run my tests and kept running into this error:

[image]

I was able to start up the tunnel properly. Here is a picture of my config file also for reference.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to make it work Leo? Can you update the question with the `wdio.conf.js` Sauce Labs config? Your `capabilities` look fine.